# How to calculate average result for certain date?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Could you help me? I have two tables.
Into the first table (activity) there are: user_id, sessions and login_time.
Into the second (payments) there's only one column - user_id.

Here's me query:

```
SELECT activity.login_time, activity.user_id, avg(activity.sessions) as 
user_sessions
FROM activity
inner JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = activity.user_id
WHERE activity.login_time ='2018-04-05' group by activity.user_id;
```

Using this query, I get such table:

```
+------------+---------+---------------
| login_time | user_id | user_sessions
+------------+---------+---------------
| 2018-04-05 |     107 |       12.0000
| 2018-04-05 |     110 |        1.0000
| 2018-04-05 |     112 |        5.0000
| 2018-04-05 |     115 |        5.0000
| 2018-04-05 |     117 |        7.0000
| 2018-04-05 |     120 |        1.0000
| 2018-04-05 |     123 |        1.0000
...
```

How should I make a query to get average:

```
+------------+------------
| login_time | avg_user_sessions 
+------------+---------
| 2018-04-05 | 4,57
```

Note: difficulty is in that user_id has duplicates

Tables

```
user_id login_time  sessions
107 2018-04-05  12
110 2018-04-05  1
112 2018-04-05  5
115 2018-04-05  5
117 2018-04-05  7
120 2018-04-05  1
123 2018-04-05  1



user_id
107
107
107
110
112
115
115
117
120
123
```

Comment: Why can't you simply group by the date? Pls add sample data and explanation of how the query should work.

Comment: @Shadow, could U help me where should I fix it in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are many `user_id` duplicates in `payments` table, you can try to use `DISTINCT` in your `user_id` from `payments` table.

but in your case, You can only select `activity` directly, don't need to `join` with `payments`, because you didn't get any column from it.

```
CREATE TABLE activity(
   login_time date,
   user_id int,
   sessions float
);

CREATE TABLE payments (
   user_id INT
);



INSERT INTO payments VALUES (107);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (107);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (110);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (112);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (115);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (115);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (117);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (120);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES (123);





INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('2018-04-05',107,12);
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('2018-04-05',110,1);
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('2018-04-05',112,5);
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('2018-04-05',115,5);
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('2018-04-05',117,7);
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('2018-04-05',120,1);
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('2018-04-05',123,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a.login_time, avg(a.sessions) as 
user_sessions
FROM activity a
inner JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM payments) p ON p.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE a.login_time ='2018-04-05' 
group by a.login_time
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/103820a/1/0)**:

```
| login_time |     user_sessions |
|------------|-------------------|
| 2018-04-05 | 4.571428571428571 |
```

Comment: thanks, I tried but this query also displays big list. But I need 1 average value

Comment: Ok could you provide some sample data from your table and show us your expect result from your sample data

Comment: the result must be (according to my example): (12 + 1 + 5 + 5 + 7 + 1 + 1)/7= 4,57

Comment: ok. But this table is formed by my query, because data for this table are in two different tables. That is difficulty

Comment: now it was the result that I expect, but it is bigger of real result because  in the second table there are duplicates(...

Comment: generally, I need average result of user_id without dublicats (there are a lot of them in 'Payments'.

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков What is your expectation when there are duplicates, could you give me some example?

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков I edit my answer you can try it. I guess you need use DISTINCT in your `user_id` from `payments`

Comment: The first query example needs to have `WHERE login_time ='2018-04-05'` in the inner SQL also otherwise you sum will never match the selected date because the sum is calculated over the complete group (login_time, user_id)

Comment: @D-Shih, thanks , but there are message: 'Unknown column 'a.user_sessions' in 'field list''

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков Sorry, it's a typo

Comment: @D-Shih , Thanks a lot! it is what i needed.

Could U give me one more hint: how can I calculate such values for a few dates  (each date in each row)?

Comment: Did you mean you want to get each day `avg`?

Comment: @D-Shih, there's no necessity, I did It by muself, thanks!

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков No problem glad to help :)

Comment: @D-Shih, may I ask U one more queation? If I need to calculate average session length - do I need to have datatime type? (now I have varchar type)